# How to setup a bonded ethernet connection directly between macOS and Windows Server 2019?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, bonding, windows-server-2019

I've been having trouble connecting a macOS 10.13 High Sierra server to a Windows Server 2019 server with a bonded ethernet connection consisting of 3 directly connected ethernet adapters. Windows seems fine, but macOS is giving an error about `802.3ad` being unavailable.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working by setting up a bonded set on macOS with the following command:

```
# First get your network interfaces:
$ networksetup -listallhardwareports
# Then create the bond with the appropriate ports:
$ networksetup -createBond BondName en1 en2 en7
```

I then manually assign an IP + subnet via `System Preferences -> Network` (ie, `192.168.10.1` + `255.255.255.0`)

Then on the Windows Server 2019 you go to `Server Manager -> Local Server`, `Bond` (click on "Disabled" to configure), then go to the `Teams` section and `TASKS` dropdown `-> New Team`:
[image: new team]

Then select the ethernet ports you want to be part of your team and the key part select `LACP` for the teaming mode:

[image: settings]

Finally go to `Network Connections -> Bond -> Properties` and set your IP statically for a connection (eg, `192.168.10.2` + `255.255.255.0`).

You're done!